# Application inexplicably failing capturing screenshots

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, screenshot

I have an odd issue that I have been trying to pin down for awhile. Essentially my application opens up various URL's using chrome (data from an array), takes a picture of them, saves them, and continues on looping through the array. The application successfully launches and runs, but variably it fails (usually between 2-5 days). When it fails, chrome no longer appears to open but the application continues to 'run'. Here is the error that is being produced from my try/catches:

> at System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(Int32 sourceX, Int32 sourceY, Int32 destinationX, Int32 destinationY, Size blockRegionSize, CopyPixelOperation copyPixelOperation)
>      at Command_Center_Screen_Capture_Agent.Form1.Capture(String name)

My only working theory right now is that there might be an issue with the memory since it's failing to take the picture and failing to open the browser, but I'm not sure how  to test that theory.

{UPDATE} Going through the logs on all of my servers, I noticed that while only some had the error above, all of them had the following error:

> at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
>      at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageFormat format)
>      at Command_Center_Screen_Capture_Agent.Form1.Capture(String name) in SERVER REDACTED\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Command Center Screen Capture Agent\Command Center Screen Capture Agent\Form1.cs:line 170

This error appears to always be the last error before the system stopped logging and (theoretically) failed.

The code in question is:

```
            try
        {
            GFX.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,
                                        Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y,
                                        0,
                                        0,
                                        Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size,
                                        CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Noticed without this if the program was running before skyvision was opened an occasional error popped up
            error_logging(e.StackTrace);
        }
        // Save the screenshot to the specified path
        try
        {
            String filePath = @"\" + pictureNames[count] + ".png";
            // MessageBox.Show("Saving file to: " + FILEPATH_LOCATION + forTesting);
            BIT.Save(@FILEPATH_LOCATION + @filePath, ImageFormat.Png);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            count++;
            _capture.Enabled = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            error_logging(e.StackTrace);
            //Save error without breaking in case issue with path
            //MessageBox.Show("CAPTURE ERROR: \n\n" + e.StackTrace);
        }
```

The full source code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Command_Center_Screen_Capture_Agent
{
    public partial class Form1 : MaterialSkin.Controls.MaterialForm
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //Array storage for URLs and pic names
        public static String[] URLS;
        public static String[] pictureNames; //Used to save picture by name


        //Data
        static List<String> URL_LIST = new List<String>();
        static List<String> URL_DESC = new List<String>();
        static String base_url_1 = "URL_OMITTED";
        static String base_url_2 = "URL_OMITTED";
        static Configuration configManager = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

        int count = 0;

        //Create a new bitmap.
        static Image BIT = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                                       Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height,
                                       PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        // Create a graphics object from the bitmap.
        Graphics GFX = Graphics.FromImage(BIT);

        string FILEPATH_LOCATION = (@"FILEPATH_OMITTED");
        string ERROR_LOGGING = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Error Logs");

        private void error_logging(string line)
        {
            try
            {
                Guid filename = Guid.NewGuid();
                string targetPath = Path.Combine(ERROR_LOGGING, filename + ".txt");
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter file =
                new System.IO.StreamWriter(targetPath))
                {
                    file.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception E)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failure Writing Error log. " + E.StackTrace);
            }
        }

        private void load_data()
        {
            //Attempt to load data
            try
            {
                string line;
                System.IO.StreamReader file =
                    new System.IO.StreamReader(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "data.txt");
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line.Contains("SERVERS:"))
                    {
                        URL_LIST = line.Substring(8).Split(',').ToList();
                    }
                    if (line.Contains("DESC:"))
                    {
                        URL_DESC = line.Substring(5).Split(',').ToList();
                    }
                }

                file.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception criticalError)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Critical Error. Could not access data file. Closing application. \n\n" + criticalError.StackTrace);
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }

        private void build_error_log()
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(ERROR_LOGGING))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(ERROR_LOGGING);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            build_error_log();
            load_data();
            Checkpath();
            cycleTimeTxtBx.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.TimeToLoadPage.ToString();
        }

        private bool Checkpath()
        {
            this.Hide();
            if (Directory.Exists(FILEPATH_LOCATION))
            {
                return (true);
            }
            else
            {
                DirectoryInfo dir = Directory.CreateDirectory(FILEPATH_LOCATION);
                return false;
            }
        }

        private void Capture(string name)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!Checkpath())
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception whoops)
            {
                error_logging(whoops.StackTrace);
                //Console.WriteLine(whoops);
            }
            // Take the screenshot from the upper left corner to the right bottom corner.
            try
            {
                GFX.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,
                                            Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y,
                                            0,
                                            0,
                                            Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size,
                                            CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                error_logging(e.StackTrace);
            }
            // Save the screenshot to the specified path
            try
            {
                String filePath = @"\" + pictureNames[count] + ".png";
                BIT.Save(@FILEPATH_LOCATION + @filePath, ImageFormat.Png);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                count++;
                _capture.Enabled = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                error_logging(e.StackTrace);
                //Save error without breaking in case issue with path
                //MessageBox.Show("CAPTURE ERROR: \n\n" + e.StackTrace);
            }
            KillChrome();
        }

        private void KillChrome()
        {
            try
            {
                Process[] procsChrome = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
                foreach (Process pro in procsChrome)
                {
                    pro.Kill();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                error_logging(e.StackTrace);
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }


        private void _capture_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Assume that the URL array hasn't been setup
            if (URLS == null || URLS.Length < 1)
            {
                URLS = URL_LIST.ToArray();
                pictureNames = URL_DESC.ToArray();
            }
            try
            {
                Process process = new Process();
                process.StartInfo.FileName = "chrome.exe";


                if (count < URLS.Length)
                {
                    string sysCode = URLS[count];
                    string market;
                    int delimIndex = sysCode.IndexOf("|");
                    market = sysCode.Substring(delimIndex + 1);
                    sysCode = sysCode.Substring(0, delimIndex);
                    string useable_url = base_url_1 + sysCode + base_url_2 + market;
                    process.StartInfo.Arguments = useable_url + " --start-maximized --incognito --new-window";
                }
                else
                {
                    count = 0;
                    string sysCode = URLS[count];
                    string market;
                    int delimIndex = sysCode.IndexOf("|");
                    market = sysCode.Substring(delimIndex + 1);
                    sysCode = sysCode.Substring(0, delimIndex);
                    string useable_url = base_url_1 + sysCode + base_url_2 + market;
                    process.StartInfo.Arguments = useable_url + " --start-maximized --incognito --new-window";
                }
                process.Start();
                _capture.Enabled = false;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(Properties.Settings.Default.TimeToLoadPage * 1000);
                Capture("no");
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                error_logging(error.StackTrace);
                //MessageBox.Show(error.StackTrace);
            }
        }

        private void startBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _capture.Enabled = true;
            this.Hide();
            notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
        }

        private void saveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Properties.Settings.Default.TimeToLoadPage = Convert.ToInt32(cycleTimeTxtBx.Text);
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Unable to parse cycle timer. Please only use integers when setting the cycle time.", "Parsing Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                cycleTimeTxtBx.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.TimeToLoadPage.ToString();
            }
        }

        private void notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Clicked");
            Show();
            _capture.Enabled = false;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The error you've provided looks like a partial paste of the stack trace.  You need to provide the actual error.

Comment: Unfortunately it's the exact error that's produced. I haven't omitted any of the error log.

Comment: In your catch block, it should say `catch (Exception e)` or something similar.  What does `e.Message` say?

Comment: This is run in a production environment where the errors are logged into a text file. I could add in the code to log e.Message instead of the stack trace, but it would likely be a few days before the application crashed and produced viable information. If that is what needs to happen however, I can produce those logs.

Comment: Please see the above edits which include the error message I believe is the actual culprit behind the failing application.

Comment: Yeah, looks like you're going to need to shore up your logging and capture some better error messages.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Not sure if you're still following this thread, but I received the additional error message from the logs requested. Unfortunately, I don't believe these are any more helpful. Using e.Message only produced:

"The operation completed successfully"